# Applet in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, applet

My aim is to host my applet to google app enigne.

I have made a jar of my applet, I have placed the jar into WEB-INF/lib directory but still when I write applet tag in my jsp page as

```
<applet code="myPackage.MyClass" archive="myapplet.jar" width="600" height="480"/>
```

The applet is not showing in the browser.

I am using eclipse with GAE plugin

Please Guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Try puttIng the JAR into the same directory as the JSP file.

Comment: I have did the same, but it is not showing up. Even I added the jar to build path but still of no use